# Plotting data from two files after performing mathematical operation between them, with gnuplot for windows

Tags: gnuplot

something didn't go well... maybe it is the datetime format... the first file is like
01/11/2021 00:15:00 15.0    70.0    0.10    1010.0  0.8 228 1.4 0.0
01/11/2021 00:30:00 14.8    71.0    0.20    1010.0  1.0 200 1.9 0.0
01/11/2021 00:45:00 14.6    73.0    0.30    1010.0  0.8 142 1.4 0.0
01/11/2021 01:00:00 14.6    74.0    0.20    1010.0  1.2 147 2.0 0.0
and the second, like
01/11/2021 00:30    15,610  0,0 -1,257  18,15   60,54   0,153   69,74   32,81
01/11/2021 01:00    15,380  0,0 -1,008  18,03   62,31   0,400   120,60  25,78
(note that in this latter case, time does not have seconds); date and time format, I've written just before plotting the $Data, that is: set xdata time, set timefmt "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M" and set xrange ["01/11/2021 00:00":"01/11/2021 03:00"] ). Let's say I want to subtract column 5 (not counting the datetime columns) of text2, from column 2 of text 1. In this case, file1 has 8 colums (not counting datetime columns) and file2 too, but I might have more colums in file2 in the future. So it's all about subtracting data from two files only from the same timestamp, but one file has more timestamp data compared to the other one (though fortunately, x-entries of the 2nd file are cointained among the x-entries of the 1st file). Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! So, the number of rows in the two files are not equal, but about double in the first file. Are the numbers in the first column strictly increasing or may they contain multiple identical x-values?

Comment: I'm confused... first column is timedata? How many columns? Where are the odd and even values? If my answer doesn't answer your question, please edit your question and clarify by adding "real" data.

Comment: Thank you very much Theozh... perfect answer to my case since the numbers in the 1st column of both files are increasing with no multiple indentical values... like this:                          
01/11/2021 00:15:00 15.0 70.0 0.10 1010.0 0.8 228 1.4 0.0
01/11/2021 00:30:00 14.8 71.0 0.20 1010.0 1.0 200 1.9 0.0            01/11/2021 00:45:00       14.1 73.0  etc.  while the other is                                                                                                            01/11/2021 00:30 15,610 0,0 -1,257 18,15 60,54 0,153 69,74 01/11/2021 01:00    15,380     0,0   etc.

Comment: Don't worry, it's all fine... even and odd meant to simplify the question... indeed they are timedata, one of them every 15 min and the other every 30 min. But it will work just the same

Comment: It's getting more confusing. Please edit your question and exactly describe what you have and what you want. With your recent edit you don't mention the odd and even values. Please provide e.g. 10 lines of each datafile and re-formulate your question. Now, I'm guessing that you want to subtract data from two files only from the same timestamp, but one file has more (and other) timestamp data compared to the other one, correct?

Comment: oops... a little detail which you did not mention: the first file has point as decimal separator and the second file has comma as decimal separator, correct or mistake?

Comment: That's right, I've just realized that, and so I've written set decimalsign locale  before set table $Data2, but it did not work as I expected... looks like you have built file $Data with a column with '.' and another column with ',' and now, subtracting them might be a bit tough... unfortunately I don't generate file2 but receive it from another person... should I necessarily change the decimalsign every time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variety of tools to merge your datafiles into one. Under Linux you have some "intrinsic" tools like `awk`, `sed`, etc., however, under Windows
you are rather limited unless you install, e.g. CoreUtils from [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).

If my assumption about unique, regular and strictly increasing x-values in your data is correct, you could do it with gnuplot only with the following workaround:

1. plot your first file into a datablock `$Data1` using every second value starting from the second value (note: counting starts from 0)
2. plot your second file into another datablock `$Data2`.
3. print all lines to a third datablock `$Data` by merging the two respective lines of the first two datablocks
4. plot `$Data` with whatever mathematical operations. The third column of the second file becomes now the fifth column

**Data:**

`file1.txt`

```
1   0.1
2   0.2
3   0.3
4   0.4
5   0.5
6   0.6
7   0.7
8   0.8
```

`file2.txt`

```
2   1.2   3.2
4   1.4   3.4
6   1.6   3.6
8   1.8   3.8
```

**Code:** (requires gnuplot >=5.2)

```
### mathematical operation on two files
reset session

set table $Data1
    plot 'file1.txt' u 1:2 every 2::1 w table    # every second value starting from the second value
set table $Data2
    plot 'file2.txt' u 1:2:3 w table
unset table

set print $Data
    do for [i=1:|$Data1|] {
        print sprintf("%s %s", $Data1[i], $Data2[i])    # concatenate two lines into one
    }
set print

plot $Data u 1:($2+$5) w lp pt 7 lc "red"
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: @ifffam If you have some timedata for the x-axis you need to use some datetime format, e.g. `plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")):2 w lp`

Comment: I've tried this but did not work ("all points y value undefined!"). Just for learning (though you already gave me the solution for a much more general case): plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")):($2+$5) w lp pt 7 lc "red" should work I guess... so maybe it's the construction of Data1 and Data2 (which are later merged in Data) what fails... (I have entered the time format after ```set table $Data1``` & Data2). In order to simplify, both files have the same decimalsign and datafile separator. file1.txt has timestamp format like "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M" and file2.txt, like "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarize what I understood from your modified question:

- you have two files which have two different decimal separators: `"."` and `","`
- the two files have different timestamp formats: `"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"` and `"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"`
- the two files have different number of timestamps and different time intervals, but some timestamps are identical.
- Now, you want to do a mathematical operation on two columuns from the two files, but only for those having identical timestamps.

**Data:** (some more points added for illustration)

`'SO70191250_data1.dat'`

```
01/11/2021 00:15:00 15.0 70.0 0.10 1010.0 0.8 228 1.4 0.0
01/11/2021 00:30:00 14.8 71.0 0.20 1010.0 1.0 200 1.9 0.0
01/11/2021 00:45:00 14.6 73.0 0.30 1010.0 0.8 142 1.4 0.0
01/11/2021 01:00:00 14.6 74.0 0.20 1010.0 1.2 147 2.0 0.0
01/11/2021 04:00:00 11.1 74.0 0.20 1010.0 1.2 147 2.0 0.0
01/11/2021 04:44:44 11.1 74.0 0.20 1010.0 1.2 147 2.0 0.0
01/11/2021 06:00:00 22.2 74.0 0.20 1010.0 1.2 147 2.0 0.0
```

`'SO70191250_data2.dat'`

```
01/11/2021 00:30 15,610 0,0 -1,257 18,15 60,54 0,153 69,74 32,81
01/11/2021 01:00 15,380 0,0 -1,008 18,03 62,31 0,400 120,60 25,78
01/11/2021 02:00 15,380 0,0 -1,008 18,03 55,55 0,400 120,60 25,78
01/11/2021 04:00 15,380 0,0 -1,008 18,03 55,55 0,400 120,60 25,78
01/11/2021 04:22 15,380 0,0 -1,008 18,03 66,66 0,400 120,60 25,78
01/11/2021 06:00 15,380 0,0 -1,008 18,03 66,66 0,400 120,60 25,78
```

**Solution 1:**  use whatever programming language to prepare the data (i.e. modify decimal separator, find identical timestamps, do the mathematical operation, etc.) such that gnuplot can easily plot the final result.

**Solution 2:** gnuplot-only. This will get a bit lengthy.

First of all, the different decimal separators:
You can set the following: (check `help decimalsign`)

```
set decimalsign locale "French"   # set input/output decimalsign to comma ("German" and others should also work)
set decimalsign "."               # explicitely set output decimalsign to point (only with gprintf() command)
```

With this you can change your "decimal comma" input file into a "decimal point" datablock.

In the earlier version of the question you wrote that the time interval of the first file is half the interval of the second file, i.e. every second timestamp for the first file would correspond to a timestamp in the second file.
For the following solution, this condition is not necessary it will do the desired mathematical operation only for those timestamps which are identical. They even don't have to be ordered. Only requirement is that there should not be two identical timestamps in the same file and the timestamps should not contain fractions of seconds.

**Overview about the general procedure:**

1. write your files with the columns of interest into datablocks `$Temp1` and `$Temp2` where the decimalsign of the second file will be changed from `","` to `"."`.
2. at the same time, change the different timestamps to the same format (here: seconds since the Unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00) and additionally add a litte offset of `0.1` and `0.2` indicating the origin from the first and second file, respectively.
3. merge the two datablocks `$Temp1` and `$Temp2` into the datablock `$Temp3`
4. the gnuplot option `smooth` can be used to sort these timestamps into another datablock `$Temp4`. Hence, you will get the identical timestamps (with offset) and corresponding data in successive lines.

Example of `$Temp4`:

```
1635725700.1  15  i
1635726600.1  14.8  i
1635726600.2  60.54  i
1635727500.1  14.6  i
1635728400.1  14.6  i
1635728400.2  62.31  i
1635732000.2  55.55  i
1635739200.1  11.1  i
1635739200.2  55.55  i
1635740520.2  66.66  i
1635741884.1  11.1  i
1635746400.1  22.2  i
1635746400.2  66.66  i
```

5. Create yet another datablock `$Temp5` according to the following: if two successive lines have a timestamp difference of `0.1` (to be sure, check less than `1`: `t2-t1<1`) then subtract the y values of these lines, otherwise assign `NaN`.

Example of `$Temp5`:

```
1635725700.0  NaN  u
1635726600.0  NaN  u
1635726600.0  45.74  i
1635727500.0  NaN  u
1635728400.0  NaN  u
1635728400.0  47.71  i
1635732000.0  NaN  u
1635739200.0  NaN  u
1635739200.0  44.45  i
1635740520.0  NaN  u
1635741884.0  NaN  u
1635746400.0  NaN  u
1635746400.0  44.46  i
```

**Code:**

```
### column operation on two files with different timestamps and decimalsigns
reset session

FILE1 = 'SO70191250_data1.dat'
FILE2 = 'SO70191250_data2.dat'

# get datafile into datablock with unix time and offset
set table $Temp1
    plot FILE1 u (sprintf("%.1f",timecolumn(1,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")+0.1)):3 w table
unset table

# modify decimalsign from comma to point with unix time and offset
set decimalsign locale "French"   # set input decimalsign to comma ("German" and other should also work)
set decimalsign "."               # set output decimalsign to point (works only with gprintf() command)
set table $Temp2
    plot FILE2 u (gprintf("%.1f",timecolumn(1,"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")+0.2)):(gprintf("%g",$7)) w table
unset table
set decimalsign locale "English"

# append two datablocks
set print $Temp3
    do for [i=1:|$Temp1|] { print $Temp1[i] }
    do for [i=1:|$Temp2|] { print $Temp2[i] }
set print

# sort datablock by timestamp with offset
set table $Temp4
    set format x "%.1f"             # user 1 decimal format output
    plot $Temp3 u 1:2 smooth freq
unset table
print $Temp4

# make difference of y values only if difference in timestamp is <1
set table $Temp5
    plot t2=y2=NaN $Temp4 u (t1=t2,t2=$1,int($1)):(y1=y2,y2=$2, t2-t1<1 ? y2-y1 : NaN)
unset table
print $Temp5

set key top center
set format x "%d/%m\n%H:%M" time
set xtics 3600
set grid x,y
set datafile missing NaN

plot $Temp1 u (int($1)):2 w lp pt 7 lc "red" ti "File1", \
     $Temp2 u (int($1)):2 w lp pt 7 lc "web-green" ti "File2", \
     $Temp5 u 1:2 w lp pt 7 lc "blue" ti "Difference
### end of code
```

**Result:** (difference will only be calculated for identical timestamps in the two files)

[image]

Comment: What a phenomenal work of you, theozh... and indeed it worked ! Best of all, it is appliccable to a vast number of cases. In my case, every second timestamp for the first file (every 15 min. starting from 00:15:00) corresponds to a timestamp in the second file (every 30 min. starting from 00:30), so it is a simpler case that the general one, a bit like the first solution you gave me. In the case I have a '.' as decimalsign in both files, should I use your previous (and much simpler) solution but just including some datetime format for the x-axis just before plotting $Data ? Thx!

Comment: @ifffam glad to hear that it's working for you. On StackOverflow: thanks=upvote/accept ;-)

Comment: I would like so much to upvote/accept but all I see is a button with "Votes" written on it... I've clicked but I've seen nothing else. I'd appreciate if you could tell me how to upvote. I take this opportunity to ask you something, hopefully very simple... if my two data files have some header (some comments at the beginning), is there a way to make your code ignore them ? (otherwise, the 'difference' plot is not displayed) or should I always eliminate the header beforehand?

Comment: @ifffam  Next to the answer are arrows for up/down-voting and only for the asker a checkmark for accepting. Click on it. Voting you can do if you have >=15 reputation. For ignoring headerlines: plotting to a datablock should remove headerlines. You can also explicitly skip them, e.g. `plot $Data u 1:2 skip 4` which will skip 4 lines from the beginning (check `help skip`).

Comment: @ifffam have you found the upvote/accept buttons in the meantime in order to mark this question as solved?